# Detecting and passing though touch events to an MKMapView

Tags: ios, dictionary, touch

I'd like to detect touch events going to an MKMapView but not interfere with them. Anyone have any suggestions for this?

I've tried subclassing MKMapView and calling super on touchesBegan et al to no avail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs this I was able to do this by overriding

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

on UIWindow and handling my events there before passing them off.